# Google login button on /users/login not responding to clicks. Error in console

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I'm unable to login via the /users/login page by clicking the 'Google' button. I noticed an error in the Developer Tools but I'm unsure if this is responsible for the button not working.

[image]

Comment: Apologies for this - we're doing massive changes to auth to rip out OpenID and everything that went with it to prep for some more work incoming and I missed a variable scope here. A fix is building through our tiers now and should be live in about 10 minutes.

Comment: No worries! I'll accept Adam's response once I see the fix come through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`currentPage` ended up not being correctly scoped in the JS there. Sorry about that, a fix is rolling out ASAP.

Thanks for the report!